# How long after Ahsoka left the Jedi order did Order 66 happen?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

According to the last few episodes of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* (which showed Ahsoka's story arc), it seems that Order 66 happened only a few days after Ahsoka left the Jedi order.

- After leaving the Jedi, she went directly to Coruscant Underworld and crashed into mech sisters. She spent one day there maybe.
- With the mech sisters, she went to trade spices and got captured by a crime syndicate. The whole thing lasted for a few days.
- Then she tried to get help from the Jedi to capture Maul on Mandalore, but they didn't help because Separatists attacked Coruscant (where Dooku would die later).
- On Mandalore, she spent a couple of days and captured Maul.
- Then, on her way back, Rex received Order 66.

The whole thing seemed to happen within a week.

Is there any official word on this?

How long is the gap (in days) between Ahsoka leaving the Jedi Order and the execution of Order 66?

Comment: We might have to sort out exactly how much of a time period RotS covers first...an impossible task. :(

Comment: @Kitkat A few sources, [including this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/how-long-in-universe-were-each-of-the-star-wars-movies), say 4 days (with the caveat that she somehow hid her pregnancy at the start).

Answer (score 6):

In Clone Wars 5x20, Ahsoka is expelled from the Jedi Order. **All of Seasons 6 and 7 come ***after*** 5x20**. In Season 6, **Ahsoka makes approximately one appearance** in aiding Anakin and Obi-Wan in their search for Maul (6x5). Season 6 has two major storylines (in my opinion): Tup and Fives' search for the inhibitor chips and Yoda's search for truth. Then Season 7 comes along in the following order:

- **7x5-7x8** (The mech sisters storyline)
- **7x1-7x4** (The Bad Batch's storyline)
- **7x9-7x12** (The Maul/Mandalore storyline)

(It should probably be noted that Season 7's finale was **a culmination of** *1)* Disney's explanation of what happened at Mandalore, *2)* Ahsoka's storyline and RotS continuity, *3)* Order 66 and wrapping up The Clone Wars.)

So this shows that Ahsoka is *out of the plotline* from the end of Season 5 and basically the entire Season 6. Therefore I'd say it's probably somewhere around a month or two, seeing as the last episodes of Season 7 (7x9-7x12) coincide directly with RotS. So it's really **hard to tell** but again I would say **1-2 months**, depending on how long Season 6 took (and I haven't watched it in a while).

If you'd like a bit more info on the chronological order of TCW, then check out [Disney's canon of it](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder). That should clear up things a little bit.

I hope that answered your question!

Comment: But, in the mech sister storyline, it seemed like Ahsoka had just left the Jedi order.

Comment: @HarleyQuinn the thing is, with the mech sisters, she's actually wandered a little around Coruscant and it's unknown if she checked out nearby planets.