# Are things shown but not named in Star Wars movies still G-level canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

If an alien of a certain species is shown (but never named, or does anything) in Star Wars movie, and then given a name/backstory/whatnot in a C-level book, is that alien species (and the facts about it) considered a G-level canon or a C-level canon?

Or is it nuanced? (e.g. the existance is G-level but any details are still C-level)?

Comment: Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/are-there-vampires-in-star-wars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything that is explicitly stated in a G-Canon source is G-Canon and nothing else, the rest lies in a lower level of canon. A good example is the group of bounty hunters Darth Vader mandates to find the Millennium Falcon.

[image: the group of bounty hunters]

They are all named in the [Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330145057/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml)

> The group standing before Vader is a bizarre array of
>   galactic fortune hunters: There is Bossk, a slimy, tentacled
>   monster with two huge, bloodshot eyes in a soft baggy face;
>   Zuckuss and Dengar, two battle-scarred, mangy human types;
>   IG-88, a battered, tarnished chrome war droid; and Boba Fett,
>   a man in a weapon-covered armored space suit.
>
> VADER: ...there will be a substantial reward for the one who finds
>   the Millennium Falcon. You are free to use any methods necessary, but
>   I want them alive. No disintegrations.

So their names and appearances are all G-level, but not their back stories.
From [Canon article on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon#Canon_in_the_Holocron_continuity_database) :

> G, T, C and S together form the overall Star Wars continuity. Each ascending level typically overrides the lower ones; for example, Boba Fett's back story was radically altered with the release of *Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones*, forcing the retcon of older source material to fall in line with the new G-canon back story. However, this is not always absolute, and the resolution of all contradictions is handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: is there a specific "official" confirmation for "but not theirs back story" bit? This is also how I parse the Wookipedia article, but I am looking for an official (general or specific to this case) example from LucasEmpire. +1

Comment: @DVK If you check the [wikipedia article about Star Wars canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon), you will find all the quotes you needs. They go even further, separating all 6 movies from the whole G, T, C and S canon nomenclature. There is George Lucas's world and the extended universe. Everything that happened in the EU could be happening in a parallel universe, or be revealed to be dream, with a snap of George Lucas's fingers.

Comment: Even G-level canon can get changed. Such as Obi-Wan not having used "Obi-Wan" since before Luke's birth. Along comes Ep III, and shows that to be wrong.

Comment: @aramis Only by a couple of minutes, but [Obi-Wan  using is name after Luke's birth](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/when-did-obi-wan-change-his-name-to-ben/17879#17879) is is a small issue when you compare it to [Leia having memories of her mother](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/how-does-leia-have-memories-of-her-mother).