# Why didn't the Alliance send for Yoda instead of Obi-Wan?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, obi-wan-kenobi, yoda

We all knew from ANH that Leia was on a mission to bring Obi-Wan to Alderaan.

Now, in Rogue One we saw Mon asking Bail Organa to call "his jedi friend". Since Yoda always took a position of leadership both among the Jedi Order and among the Republic, **shouldn't the Alliance have called for him, instead of Obi-Wan?** Bail also knew that Yoda was in hiding, they meet together at the end of Episode III.

I realize that Yoda is in hiding so the Emperor and Vader would not feel his presence. Also, I know he said to Obi-Wan:

> **Yoda:** Until the time is right disappear, we will.

Meaning they would stay in hiding until it was time to train Luke. But, since you are already going to call for a Jedi for help, why Obi-Wan and not Yoda? Or even both?

Comment: Or why not send for both Jedi and not just one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Bail Organa has a *close* relationship with Obi-Wan.**

> She was on the same wavelength as him. **Obi-Wan Kenobi had been a
> faithful friend long before he’d become one of the galaxy’s most
> hunted fugitives.** Bail didn’t want to disturb the man, but things had
> finally become that desperate. **“He served me well during the Clone
> Wars and has lived in hiding since the Emperor’s purge. Yes, I will
> send for him.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

**Bail knows precisely where Obi-Wan is living (not just "*somewhere on Dagobah*").**

> *“Cliegg Lars still lives on Tatooine, **I think-and Anakin’s stepbrother
> … Owen, that’s it, and his wife, Beru, still work the moisture farm
> outside Mos Eisley …”***
>
> *“As close to kinfolk as the boy can come,” Yoda said approvingly. “But
> Tatooine, not like Alderaan it is-deep in the Outer Rim, a wild and
> dangerous planet.”*
>
> *“Anakin survived it,” Obi-Wan said. “Luke can, too. And I can-well, I
> could take him there, and watch over him. Protect him from the worst
> of the planet’s dangers, until he can learn to protect himself.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Been a while since I watched Sith; did Organa even know Yoda was on Dagobah?  I mean, until Ben's ghost told Luke, he didn't seem to know.  Might have been a good idea to tell him, 'Hey, there's another Jedi master, living on this swamp planet.  He might be able to teach you some more stuff.'