# Why didn't the Tantive IV jump to hyperspace in episode IV?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In Star Wars episode IV *A New Hope* we see a Star Destroyer chasing the Tantive IV, which was carrying the stolen Death Star plans. Is there a known reason the rebels didn't jump to hyperspace like:

- The hyperspace recently having been used and overheated

or perhaps

- The Tantive IV having no hyperdrive

or even

- The Star Destroyer broke it while shooting at the ship

Are any of these the reason, or does nobody know?

Comment: Tantive IV _had_ a hyperdrive - it's seen in action in the last scene of _Rogue One_.

Comment: when E4 opens - they have reached the destination (Tatooine) - they aren't really interested in running as much as delivering the stolen data

Comment: Excuse my ignorence of Rogue One, but why was Tatooine the destination? Why wasn't the destination the rebel fleet?

Comment: Answered here: [Why specifically was Obi-Wan Kenobi the “only hope” of Princess Leia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80654/70236)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Tantive IV was damaged very shortly after it arrived in the Tatooine system. With the main reactor and the sensor array out of action (along with the main engine to take them to the nearest safe hyperdrive exit), using the hyperdrive engines to flee simply wasn't an option.

> *Bursts of laserfire streaked after the consular starship Tantive IV,
> which was racing for the planet Tatooine. The ship was fleeing from
> the Devastator, an immense Imperial Star Destroyer that was firing
> nearly all its turbolasers at the elusive ship. **Both vessels had just
> entered Tatooine’s orbit when the Devastator’s lasers scored a direct
> hit on the Tantive IV’s primary sensor array. The array exploded, and
> the blast overloaded the starboard shield projector — which caused
> another explosion, damaging the power generator system and triggering
> a chain reaction throughout the ship. With no starboard shield and no
> power to its engines, the Tantive IV was effectively crippled.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope - junior novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

In the original (George Lucas) novelisation, we get a view from inside the ship as well.

> ***One of those probing, questing beams succeeded in touching the fleeing
> ship, striking its principal solar fin.** Gemlike fragments of metal and
> plastic erupted into space as the end of the fin disintegrated. The
> vessel seemed to shudder.*
>
> ...
>
> *“Did you hear that?” he inquired rhetorically of his patient
> companion, referring to the throbbing sound. **“They’ve shut down the
> main reactor and the drive.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

**Retcon job, and not a very good one**

Opening crawl for New Hope (1977) says that Rebels achieved their first victory against Empire striking from their secret base, and that during battle Rebels spies managed to steal plans for Death Stars. Leia is now custodian of the plans (1:25 in clip) and she **races home** with them. Home, of course is not Tatooine but Alderaan. Therefore, she didn't come for Obi-Wan specifically. But, it looks like her ship could not make to Alderaan (damage probably ? ), so she puts plans inside R2-D2 and instructs him to find Kenobi because she knows that he lives on Tatooine.

Message by Leia is a bit confusing, she says that her mission is to bring Obi-Wan to Alderaan to Bail Organa. But we could strike that down as diplomatic white lie - Kenobi certainly didn't serve Organa in Clone Wars. She is most likely trying to establish emotional link .

Final piece of the puzzle is Vader himself, **mentioning transmissions** .

> “Several Rebel transmissions were beamed aboard this ship from Rebel spies”

This implies that Tantive IV received plans remotely, and was not part of "first Rebel victory". Full story, before retcon in Rouge One, would be something like : After first Rebel victory, Leia's ship posing as diplomatic vessel, receives transmissions from Rebel Spies containing Death Star plans . Unfortunately, Vader discovers transmissions, and starts pursuing Tantive IV which gets damaged in the process and cannot continue to Alderaan. Leia remembers that Obi-Wan lives on nearby Tatooine, and sends plans to him.

Comment: [Rouge One?](https://i.redd.it/xwu74kdhbz3y.jpg)

Comment: In the original novelisation (written by George Lucas) it's made abundantly clear that her mission was to meet Obi-Wan in person, explain the situation and take him (and the plans for the Death Star) to Alderaan. "*“I regret that I am unable to present my father’s request to you in person. My mission to meet personally with you has failed. Hence I have been forced to resort to this secondary method of communication.*"

Comment: @Valorum And in original movie which is higher level of canon, Leia races home. Obviously, something is wrong there :P

Comment: Races home...via a stop-off.

Comment: @Valorum Casually stops at Tatooine to pick up Obi-Wan, while carrying Death Star plans and being chased by Vader himself :D

Comment: It's pretty clear that they weren't expecting to be ambushed on arrival. They thought they'd made a clean getaway.

Comment: @Valorum After Rouge One this looks ludicrous. They barely managed to escape, and certainly know about Imperial technology that could track hyperspace jumps and calculate possible routes. What really happened is not so good retcon job. I suspect that original story had Leia's ship receiving transmission (not hard-copy) and then being chased&damaged by Vader and unable to jump to Alderaan .

Comment: Er, no. There's no indication that they had to stop at Tatooine for any other reason than to pick up Obi-Wan. Could you be getting mixed up with Han and Leia's impromptu stop at Cloud City?

Comment: @Valorum According to current canon, Leia and crew barely escaped with their lives from Scariff. Not only that, they are carrying plans of Death Stars with them, an Vader is pursuing. And then, they decided to stop at Tatooine to pick up Obi-Wan (so he could die with them :D) . Obviously, this is idiotic. Obi-Wan does not need Tantive IV to get message, he could be contacted by other means and he is capable of getting to Alderaan by any other ship. Simply admit that story was badly retconed in Rouge One .

Comment: Rogue one conflicts with the existing canon in a number of ways. What's important is that Leia was on her way to collect someone that her father told her was essential to their fight.

Comment: -1 The question doesn't mention Rogue One at all, and how they got to Tatooine doesn't matter for the Q of "why didn't they hyperspace away?". The "retcon job" doesn't answer the question, it is a non-sequitur and this whole answer and comment thread is naught but a rant. That is, unless your argument is *A New Hope* retconned **its own opening crawl**, because most of your answer shows that the movie contradicts the crawl. If so, *say that* and leave off the mention of "Rouge" One.