# Did Bail Organa and/or Princess Leia know where to find Obi-Wan on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Since we know that they were headed to Tatooine at the beginning of A New Hope (confirmed by Bail Organa's conversation with Mon Mothma in Rogue One), did they know where he resided on Tatooine? The only way I could think of that Organa would know would be if Obi-Wan told him in Revenge of the Sith (didn't happen) or he knew where Owen and Beru Lars lived. If not, has it been established how they would have found him?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Princess Leia know Obi-Wan Kenobi is "Ben" Kenobi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59931/how-does-princess-leia-know-obi-wan-kenobi-is-ben-kenobi)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59944/20774

Comment: Tatooine is a backwater planet with a small population. How hard can it be to find Lars farm (and assume OB1 is around)?

Comment: That doesn't say if she knew where he was.

Answer (score 8):

Bail was in the room when Yoda and Obi-Wan discussed splitting up the twins. He also dropped Obi-Wan off at Tatooine before delivering Padmé's body to her family on Naboo. He certainly knew that Obi-Wan would be in the near-vicinity of the Lars homestead and it's possible that he's been in contact with him more recently.

> *“Cliegg Lars still lives on Tatooine, I think-and Anakin’s stepbrother
>   **… Owen, that’s it, and his wife, Beru, still work the moisture farm
>   outside Mos Eisley …”***
>
> *“As close to kinfolk as the boy can come,” Yoda said approvingly. “But
>   Tatooine, not like Alderaan it is-deep in the Outer Rim, a wild and
>   dangerous planet.”*
>
> *“Anakin survived it,” Obi-Wan said. “Luke can, too. And I can-well, **I
>   could take him there, and watch over him.** Protect him from the worst
>   of the planet’s dangers, until he can learn to protect himself.”*

Answer (score 2):

From *Obi-Wan Kenobi* Episode 1, we know that Bail knew where Obi-Wan lived as of 10 BBY, since he shows up unannounced at Obi-Wan's cave:

[image: Screenshot of Obi-Wan Kenobi episode with Obi-Wan and Bail in a cave]

In the context of the episode, Obi-Wan seems surprised to see him there, but it's unclear whether Bail knew his specific location ahead of time or was just good at tracking him. Obi-Wan also has a communicator with a direct line to Bail, so they could apparently get in contact throughout Obi-Wan's exile, making it possible that he told Bail about his new location once he moved into his house seen in *A New Hope*.

Answer (score 0):

In the novelisation "Return of the Jedi", Obi Wan comments to Luke

> "That's what she was doing when her path crossed yours - for her foster parents had always told her to contact me on Tatooine, if her troubles became desperate."